# Let $h: G \to H$ an epimorphism. If N is a normal subgroup of H, show that $G/h^{-1}(N) \simeq H/N.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, epimorphisms

> Let $h: G \to H$ an epimorphism. If N is a normal subgroup of H, show
>   that $$G/h^{-1}(N) \simeq H/N.$$

I have the good intuition that I have to use the first isomorphism theorem.

I'm not able how to continue this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a little hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the projection $\pi\colon H\to H/N$; what is the kernel of
$\pi\circ h$? What does the homomorphism theorem say? Note that $\pi\circ h$ is surjective.